# Getting Error Build file '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/Depoto/android/build.gradle' line: 42 in react-native-android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I am developing one sample application , iOS working fine, coming to android the app was not working.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/Depoto/android/build.gradle' line: 42

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-maps'.
> Android tasks have already been created.
  This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
  android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
  Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
  continue configuring the model.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Please give me suggest anyone!